# Why do I never get the chance to enter my input?

Tags: c++, input, terminal

when I want to enter the address after the year the compiler doesn't wait for my answer

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>

using namespace std;
int main() 
{
    cout << "What year was your house built?\n";
    int year;
    cin >> year;
    cout << "What is its street address?\n";
    char address[80];
    cin.getline(address, 80);
    cout << "Year built: " << year << endl;
    cout << "Address: " << address << endl;
    cout << "Done!\n";
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please tag what language this is exactly.

Comment: Just copy pasted your code. It works fine. Can you please elaborate the error?

Comment: please replace all '\n' with endl and check.

Comment: It is working! with g++ Linux

Comment: can You check it again?

Answer (score 0):

In this case control don't wait for your input because most probably it pick the input on the stream. To overcome this situation use `endl` after each `cout` statement.

Please prefer using `endl` instead of `\n`.

```
cout << "What is its street address?\n";
```

is equivalent to

```
cout << "What is its street address?\n";
cout.flush();
```

Answer (score -2):

You dont leave the window open, try something like

```
char c;
cin >> c;
return 0;
```

at the end of the main function so your terminal will stay open.